# SQL: last id from a table selecting database

Tags: php, sql, t-sql, identity

I have the following query in my php script:

```
SELECT last_value FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'MYTABLE' AND last_value IS NOT NULL
```

This works great, it returns the last id from MYTABLE which is what I need.

But, as I'm going to have more than one database I should modify the query to select the database where MYTABLE is.

I'm doing:

```
SELECT last_value FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'mydatabase.dbo.MYTABLE' AND last_value IS NOT NULL
```

But this does not work, I get nothing in return.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: fyi: It helps to tag database questions with the database software and, if applicable, version, e.g. SQL Server 2008R2 or MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass the database name as a variable [IDENT_CURRENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) accepts a database qualified object name. e.g.:

```
SELECT  IDENT_CURRENT('mydatabase.dbo.MYTABLE');
```

---

As an unrelated aside it would be better to use:

```
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'MYTABLE');
```

Instead of

```
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'MYTABLE'
```

Since if `MYTABLE` was not in the default schema, it would fail, consider a table MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE. This returns no rows

```
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE'
```

Whereas this would:

```
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute an SQL statement, it runs in the context of a database you specified on connection. In order to query a different database you should change the database context.
Try this:

```
USE MyDatabase;

SELECT last_value FROM sys.identity_columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = 'MYTABLE' AND last_value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: can I do it from my php script?

Comment: I think so. The user should have access to MyDatabase.

Comment: But how do I add the USE MyDatabase; in my php query ?? Sorry, I deon't get it :(

Comment: Can you dynamically build a connection string for each database you wish to call it for, and use a different connection each time?